# KMV Switch, monitor not turning on

Tags: windows, terminal, internet, desktop, switch

I have  a terminal and a pc connected to my monitor through a 2 port usb displayport cable kvm switch (model cs22dp). My problem is when I click the button to switch to the pc with internet it turns on the monitor, but when I click the button to which to the terminal the screen does not turn on and I have to turn the screen off and back on in order for it to reconginize the dp cable